# Multiple lines in a horizontally-floated list item

Tags: html, css, menu, html-lists

I'm trying to create a navigation menu for my website, with the links aligned horizontally near the top of the page, and I want each link to have a short description underneath. When a user clicks on either the main link text or the description underneath, it should take them to the right page. Additionally, each menu item should have a triangle-shaped icon as the bullet. [This is a picture](http://i43.tinypic.com/2nj98ck.jpg) of what I'm trying to achieve.

I can make a list align horizontally when it's just one line. But it breaks down when I try to add more.

```
<nav id = "header-navigation">
  <ul>
    <li>
      <a href="/">
        Home
        <span class = "subnavigation">Foo!</span>
      </a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="/contact">
        Contact
         <span class = "subnavigation">Bar</span>
    </li>
  </ul>
</nav><!-- header-navigation -->
```

And in the CSS:

```
nav#header-navigation {
  margin-top: 160px;
  display: block;
}

nav#header-navigation ul li:before {
    content: url("../images/main-navigation-bullet.png");
    vertical-align: top;
}

nav#header-navigation ul li {
    display: inline;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    min-height: 22px;
}

nav#header-navigation ul li span.subnavigation {
  display: block;
  color: #999;
  font-size: 90%;
  margin-top: -10px;
  margin-left: 15px;
}
```

[This is what I get.](http://i42.tinypic.com/119qkio.jpg)

I've also tried putting a `float: left` on nav#header-navigation ul li, but that causes the list items to float all over the place, like to the top of the screen, outside of the containing div where they belong.

Another problem I've found is that Chrome doesn't display the `vertical-align: top;` attribute correctly, so the subnavigation text displays in the wrong place on that browser.

Is there a way to get this to work across browsers, or is this still the sort of thing that's best done using images?

Comment: Could you set up an example on [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/)?

Comment: Here is the new fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/9Ks9L/ It works just as I was describing. If you delete the spans with class subnavigation, the menu items display on one line like they're supposed to. It also doesn't display correctly in Chrome (at least, Ubuntu Chrome) like I said.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears the only changes you need are:

```
nav#header-navigation ul li{
    display: inline-block;
}

nav#header-navigation ul li a{
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: top;
}
```

And get rid of

```
nav#header-navigation ul li span.subnavigation {
    margin-top: -10px;
    margin-left: 15px;
}
```

After making these changes, it appears correctly in Firefox and Chromium on Linux Mint 15.

Comment: Thanks, that did the trick. I had played around with inline-block a bunch, but something else in my code must have been throwing it off. When I deleted it and then copy and pasted exactly like you had it, it started working. Still isn't displaying properly in Chrome, though.

Comment: Installed Chromium (same rendering engine as Chrome) and updated my answer. @user2242700

Comment: That isn't working for me, it's overlaying the subnavigation menus onto the main menu text. Is that not what you're seeing?

Comment: Did you get rid of the margins on `span.subnavigation`? @user2242700

Comment: Oh yeah, that does it on Chrome, but then on Firefox, the subnavigation text is below the triangle bullet, not next to it like the text above it.

Comment: It definitely does not do that for me. Did you remove all of the css I suggested earlier (especially `white-space: pre;`)?

Comment: Sorry for the delay in getting back to you. I went to sleep and then had to go to work today. What you said seems to have done the trick, maybe I just had to restart my browser. Thanks!